# Do I need a local German bank account, if I have an account in another eurozone country?

Tags: germany, eu, banking

[SEPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Euro_Payments_Area) is supposed to provide for a single Euro payments area, where direct deposits and direct debits are supposed to be unified across the eurozone.  IBAN replaces local bank account numbers.

A [question from 2016](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8888/6) complains that in practice, institutions insist on a local German bank account.  How is this now in 2018?  Should I still expect to require a German bank account in Germany, or have these problems since been resolved?

Comment: I think the only way to find out is to try it.  My *suspicion* is that it will have got much better (Vodafone will want to accept Dutch bank accounts so that Netherlanders crossing the border to work on a daily basis can have a Vodafone SIM, etc).  It didn't take long to open an account, so if you *do* have to, you can.

Comment: @MartinBonner Oh, I'm sure that I *can* — but it's one of those things that can be a bit of a "chicken and egg" hassle when starting up in a new country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory no, in practice yes.

My employer in 2024 still requires a German bank account for paying the salary.

Comment: Side note: If _the employer_ demands from you _to open_ a _new_ account with a bank, you can (additionally) charge the employer for _necessary_ banking fees associated with that new bank account. You _may_ therefore _defer_ opening a new bank account in Germany until an employer asks you to do so. This labor law rule does _not_ apply if you _already_ have _voluntarily_ opened a bank account (since it is then attributed to _personal_ lifestyle).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Interesting, but it sounds like more effort than it's worth.